# Unable to access data on flash drive

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, flash

I've copied more than 300 Go data on a 2 To flash drive, from a Ubuntu 16.04, then formatted that PC and installed Ubuntu 18.04.

The flash disk is exFAT partition, when I mounted it, I had to install some package to be able to mount it (exfat-fuse and exfat-utils). But the weird thing that I can see all the folders, but not the data within it :

```
Sys. de fichiers Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
/dev/sdb1          2,0T    267G  1,7T  14% /media/sazzabi/MAGIC
```

Can you help me please, I have me lifetime photos on that flash disk, it happened to me before and I lost more than 120 Go (with other flash disks, other PCs, etc..)

I think it's related to the chown user (same username on both PCs), and when I try to ls the folders I got :

```
ls: lecture du répertoire 'Photos/Photos Dropbox/': Erreur d'entrée/sortie
total 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It **IS** about ownership, but not quite the way you think.

Inspect the way the USB Disk is mounted, with:

```
mount | grep MAGIC
```

Then, read `man mount`, especially the sections "FILESYSTEM-INDEPENDENT MOUNT OPTIONS" and "FILESYSTEM-SPECIFIC MOUNT OPTIONS" (the "Mount options for fat" part).

Then, do something like:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw,user,users,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2 /dev/sdb1 /media/sazzabi/MAGIC
```

Then, inspect the `mount | grep MAGIC` again.

Questionner ( @seifallah-azzabi )says: (moved up from comments to improve searchability)

The first command gave me this result

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/sazzabi/MAGIC type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

after running the second command, this is the result of

```
mount | grep MAGIC 
/dev/sdb1 on /media/sazzabi/MAGIC type fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,user,uhelper=udisks2)
```

@waltinator responds:

For some reason (you're running the command from a `root` shell?), `$(id -u)` and `$(id -g)` returned `root`'s `UID` and `GID`. I expected them to return your USER `UID` and `GID`. Or you have to `umount` first.

Substitute your own `UID` and `GID`. `getent passwd $USER | cut -d: -f3,4` to see them, or `id`.

Rather than trying to `remount` on `/media/sazzabi/MAGIC`,

(only once)

```
mkdir -p $HOME/mnt/MAGIC
```

Then,

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

followed by

```
sudo mount -o rw,user,users,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2 /dev/sdb1 $HOME/mnt/MAGIC
# no "remount,", different mount point
```

Then, you should have `owner` access to the files on `$HOME/mnt/MAGIC/`.

Comment: The first command gave me this result `/dev/sdb1 on /media/sazzabi/MAGIC type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)`

Comment: after running the second command, this is the result of mount | grep MAGIC `/dev/sdb1 on /media/sazzabi/MAGIC type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,user,uhelper=udisks2)
`

Comment: but nothing happened, I can't see my files

Comment: Thank you waltinator for your detailed answer, but same thing, I plugged the device, unmounted it, created the folder, mounted it, the result is the same : I can't see my files. Could it be a problem related to the MFT ? because I can see some files with a recovery programs, but it takes way too long to load a single file.

Comment: and by the way, when I `ls -la` on the root directory of the device, the folders are owned by sazzabi, but no file is listed